# How do I exit sub where function is used?

Tags: vba, function

Was wondering if it was possible to exit sub using a function :

For example

```
Public Function test()
  Exit Sub 'does not work
End Function

Sub MySub()
  test() 'Here we should Exit MySub()
End Sub
```

But this Trigger an error. Is there a way to do this ?

**NOTE** I don't want to exit the function but I would like to exit the Sub or Stop the code execution directly into my function.

Comment: try End?  It kills the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. However, if your intent is to have `test` decide whether or not to abort `MySub`, then just return a boolean from `test` and act on it in `MySub`:

```
Sub MySub()
    If test() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good Trick I will try it out ! I will give you feed back assap

Comment: You can one-line it depending on taste: `If test() Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/exit-statement):

> Exit Function Immediately exits the Function procedure in which it
>   appears.

You should use `Exit Function` and not `Exit Sub` inside `test()`

Update:
If you wish to exit the calling sub `MySub`, you should return some value from the test function. For Example:

```
Public Function test()
  test = False
End Function

Sub MySub()
  If test() = False Then
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But this will Exit the function and Continue the Sub Execution

Comment: Upvoted since I can not accept all answer ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, please. Your function must return something in order to exit the sub. Your sub **is not automatically exited** if the function is. You must set a condition inside the sub to exit it in case of a specific function return:

```
Public Function test(a As Long, b As Long) As Boolean
  If a + b > 10 Then
    test = True
  Else
    Exit Function ' even if it is not necessary
  End If
End Function

Sub MySub()
  If Not test(5, 7) Then Exit Sub
  'do whatever...
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it would be `If test(5,6) Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Upvoted since I can not accept all answer ! Thank you